# Render template even when there's no data to be filled in placeholders

Tags: javascript, json, rendering, ejs

I am using EJS templates to render a form. Question is not specifically for EJS though, but any templating library for JavaScript.

Say my template is like

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="<%= foo %>" />
    <input type="text" name="baz" value="<%= baz %>" />
</form>
```

A JSON object is passed to `.render` method like this

```
tpl.render({foo: "bar", "baz": "qux"})
```

It fills the values in the respective input boxes and returns rendered markup which we can append to the container.

Now what I want to do is, it should get rendered even when I pass a blank object `{}`. I mean, it should return blank values for the input boxes (empty form to add something).

I know we can either use an inline `if` like `<%= (baz != undefined ? bax : "") %>`, alternatively we can make a dummy/blank JSON object like `{"foo": "", "baz": ""}`

But both of the above approaches doesn't look very good to me. Is there any better way of doing this? Keeping in mind huge forms with `input`, `select` and all other tags.

Answer (score 1):

Ya the ternary method seems like as clean as it gets - `<%= foo ? foo : '' %>`. It's probably best to handle defaults for you missing properties like underscore with it's `_.defaults()`.

Comment: But isn't there any clean way of telling rendering engine that don't substitute values and give back blank form?